# Programmatically keep everything in one tag when looping text using VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to keep all text in one tag when looping through an array of split up text

```
<template v-for="message in array">
     <span v-if="some condition">
          <a href="">{[ message }}</a>
     </span>
     <span v-else>
          {{ message }}
     </span>
</template
```

This renders span over and over like this:

```
<span>Text</span>
<span><a href="">link</a></span>
<span>text again</span>
```

How do I make it so it's just like this:

```
<span>Text <a href="">link</a> text again</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what you have done for the `v-for`, you can use `<template>` element for `v-if` and `v-else` binding as well. They will not be added to DOM.

For example, I've modified your view slightly to show how it works:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    array: [
      {
        toggle: true,
        txt: "Abc"
      },
      {
        toggle: false,
        txt: "Def"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <span>
    <template v-for="message in array">
    
       <template v-if="message.toggle">
            <a href="">{{ message.txt }}</a>
       </template>
       <template v-else>
            {{ message.txt }}
       </template>
    
    </template>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that. But now it seems it's performing a line break per text?

Comment: my bad it was my CSS that was causing the break for the a tag!